# Get the Contents of AWS Secret Manager in R

Tags: r

Let's say that I have in AWS Secret Manager with information that I'd like to use in an R script.

The AWS Secret Manager instance...

[image]

Is there a way to connect to AWSS Secret Manager from within R?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the `paws` package to get data out of the secrets manager. It looks something like

```
library(paws)
library(jsonlite)

Sys.setenv(AWS_PROFILE = "my-aws-profile", AWS_REGION = "us-east-1")

aws_sm <- paws::secretsmanager()
values <- jsonlite::fromJSON(aws_sm$get_secret_value("secret-key-name")$SecretString)
```

This will work if you have already authenticated your profile at the command line. [There are other authentication methods](https://www.paws-r-sdk.com/developer_guide/credentials/) as well